# Python functional closures without performance hit

Tags: python, scope

In my python program, I have a ton of functions that are really wrappers for more complicated functions (the more complicated functions take more arguments, so the simple functions calculate the extra arguments and pass them along with the original arguments to the complex functions). I don't want the more complicated functions to be visible from the outer scope. However, my understanding is that if you define a function inside a function every time the outer function gets called it redefines the inner function, which is wasteful. How can I hide my inner functions without redefining them over and over again? There must be some way for the interpreter to parse my file and just do the definitions once but still keep them in the inner scope.

Comment: Why don't you use `__all__` and/or a naming convention (leading underscore for private-by-convention) to control the names available for `import` from your package, rather than nesting the functions? Then you only define them once, they're not directly available *and* your structure becomes simpler.

Comment: Just move the function out. Move it to another module if you have to. You don't *have* to put your functions in a nested scope. Note that the 'performance hit' is no more so than any other object creation; you don't complain about creating a string or list in your functions, yet the cost is about the same.

Comment: @jonrsharpe To be clear, so if I had `def a(): \n \t def b(): \n \t print foo` it wouldn't redefine `b` every time I called `a`?

Comment: All Python does is a) load the already compiled code object, and b) create a function object with the right metadata and closures attached. This is hardly costly.

Comment: @RenéG no, that's not what I'm saying **at all**. I'm suggesting a completely different way to achieve your goal.

Comment: @MartijnPieters How does python know it can use the compiled code? For all it knows, the function definition changes each time. For example, I could have an if-else with a different definition in each branch, but the same name.

Comment: Smells of [premature optimazation](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/80084/is-premature-optimization-really-the-root-of-all-evil)

Comment: @RenéG: no, the code for a given function doesn't change. You are not generating that code, it is compiled *once*. If you are branching with `if..else` then either there are multiple code objects to pick from or the `if...else` branch *is part of the compiled code*.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Sorry, I've been doing too much Scheme recently :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than controlling access to your *"inner functions"* by nesting them, use either or both of:

- naming conventions (a leading underscore on a name means private-by-convention, see [the style guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#method-names-and-instance-variables)); and
- defining a list named `__all__` to specify what gets imported from the package by default (see [the tutorial on modules](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#importing-from-a-package)).

In use:

```
# define the names that get imported from this package
__all__ = ['outer_func']`

def _inner_func(...):
    """Private-by-convention inner function.""" 
    ...

def outer_func(...):
    """Public outer function to call _inner_func."""
    ...
```

This makes testing much easier, too, as you can still get direct access to `_inner_func` when necessary.

Comment: I guess I'll have to do that; my benchmarks show that defining the functions inside slows it down by about 3%, which is really a lot for such a small semantic improvement.

Answer (score -2):

I think the convention is to prepend the function name with two underscores.

(See: http://www.diveintopython.net/object_oriented_framework/private_functions.html)

Comment: It's not really private, just "name-mangled"; this should, per [the style guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#method-names-and-instance-variables) *"Generally... be used only to avoid name conflicts with attributes in classes designed to be subclassed"*.